# Getting last price from specific product on MYSQL (faster than this)

Tags: mysql, max

I'm grabbing the last price from a specific product, but performance is really slow on over 3 million prices.

Does anyone have a better way of doing this? My server is getting hammered by this slow query.

`prices.id` is used to store the id of the store in the `prices` table so I can join it with the `stores.id` from the `stores` table.

```
SELECT prices.id, prices.price, prices.timelog, prices.user_id FROM prices
WHERE prices.id IN (SELECT stores.id FROM stores WHERE city = "miami" )
AND prices.product_id = 1
AND prices.timelog IN 
  (SELECT MAX( lastprice.timelog ) 
   FROM prices AS lastprice 
   WHERE lastprice.id = prices.id AND lastprice.product_id = 1)
```

Comment: Can you please show us the indexes you have on table `prices` and `stores` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 million prices might mean your application could benefit from some denormalisation. (i.e. flag the last price in some manner, remember: write-once, read-many is often worth the overhead of a slower write).

With the current data, worth a try are:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.price, p1.timelog, p1.user_id 
FROM prices p1
JOIN stores 
ON stores.id = prices.id
AND stores.city = "miami"
LEFT JOIN prices p2
ON p2.product_id = p1.product_id
AND p2.id = p1.id
AND p2.timelog > p1.timelog
WHERE p1.product_id = 1 AND p2.id IS NULL;
```

... and another a bit faster option which always escapes me this time of night :)

Keep in mind a lot can change with the proper indexes on tables, so by all means, run an `EXPLAIN`  on the lot.

Comment: awesome, this was 4.5x faster than the original.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the table structures, I think you could do:

```
select * from prices
join stores on stores.id = prices.id
where stores.city = 'miami' and prices.product = 1
 order by timelog DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: MySQL's `top 1` would be a `LIMIT 1` on the end AFAIK.

Comment: @Richard, very nice compact rewrite

Comment: @caio, use Richard's answer and make sure `stores.id` and `prices.id` are the primary keys for those tables. Also make sure you have an index on `timelog` and on `stores.city` and on `prices.product`.

Comment: @Johan: `prices.id` does not look like a primary key. It might be better renamed to `prices.storeid`.

Comment: @ypercube, now that you mention it, it does look like a wierd join, could this be a cause of the `join using ...` disease?

Comment: @Johan: Oh, I just read it in the 3rd line in the Question: "*`prices.id` is used to store the id of the store in the `prices` table so I can join it with the `stores.id` from the `stores` table.*" Don't know how I missed it before.

Comment: LIMIT 1 is cropping the results to just one price from one random store, not one last price per store.

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
SELECT prices.id
     , prices.price
     , prices.timelog
     , prices.user_id

FROM prices
    JOIN
      ( SELECT MAX( timelog ) AS lasttimelog
        FROM prices 
        WHERE product_id = 1
      ) AS lastprice
        ON prices.timelog = lastprice.lasttimelog

WHERE EXISTS
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM stores
      WHERE prices.id = stores.id
        AND stores.city = "miami"
    )
  AND prices.product_id = 1
```

I would guess that an index on `(id,product_id,timelog)` in `products` and an index on `id` or `(city,id)` in table `stores` would help the query speed.

It would be better if you run EXPLAIN on the queries and also post the tables structure (fields, indexes, references).