# MySQL - get products with a drop in price

Tags: php, mysql, product, price

I have the following data structure for products in a custom-made e-commerce platform (still in development, so be benevolent :P).

This is the current definition for the products price table (I chose to model it in a separate fashion to do timely reports on price evolution for each given product)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commerce_products_price (
    price_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    price_offer FLOAT,
    date_added DATETIME NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (price_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I would like to get the list of products (by id) which have a drop in price. Right now, the SQL query I've simulated looks like this:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT(p1.product_id) AS product_id
FROM commerce_products_price p1 
INNER JOIN commerce_products_price p2 ON (p1.product_id = p2.product_id) AND (p2.date_added > p1.date_added)
WHERE p2.price < p1.price
```

The reasoning behind this is to get the latest two price history entries to compare each other. If the second price is lower than the first, then the product has a drop in price.

Here's an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c07cc) I've set up for you. I targeted MySQL 5.5 (which is the database engine I have in my VM).

But it's not working like I want and I'm sure I'm missing something. I chose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875988/getting-last-price-from-specific-product-on-mysql-faster-than-this) question as a base to build my query. Another thing I would like to add to this query is the ability to get the list of products with a drop in price with a given threshold (ala `DATEDIFF(...) <= 15`) but I guess it's a matter of adding something like `DATEDIFF(p1.date_added, NOW()) BETWEEN ? AND ?`.

Any hint would be greately appreciated :)

Comment: Note that price is normally DECIMAL, and DISTINCT is NOT a function, and a LEFT JOIN with a WHERE clause is an INNER JOIN ;-)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
p1.product_id
FROM commerce_products_price p1 
LEFT JOIN commerce_products_price p2 ON (p1.product_id = p2.product_id)
LEFT JOIN (
    Select p3.product_id, max(date_added) as maxD,min(date_added) as minD 
    from commerce_products_price p3
    group by p3.product_id
) p4 ON (p1.product_id = p4.product_id)
WHERE p2.price < p1.price
AND p2.date_added = p4.maxD AND p1.date_added = p4.minD
```

Comment: Hmmmm no, that's not working. The idea behind the procedure is to show all defined products with a price drop, but if the latest price is higher than the previous one, then there's no price drop but a raise.